# Compiling "bugs" in SQL Developer 4.0.0.12

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, triggers

Has anyone came across a bug in SQL Developer where on compiling a trigger, it moves around lines of code/sql causing the trigger to compile with errors?

For example, I made a change to a trigger last night and hit compile. It came back with an error saying that I was missing an End If at the end of the trigger. It had removed two END IFS from an IF statement I had further down in my trigger.

I amended this and compiled it again, this time successfully. However, I found out this morning that it had moved around my INSERT INTO  ordering!

For example, I had:

```
insert into table(
A, B, C, D,
E, F, G, H,
I, J, K, L,
M, N, O, P)
VALUES (
A, B, C, D,
E, F, G, H,
I, J, K, L,
M, N, O, P
)
```

After I compiled it became:

```
insert into table(
A, B, C, D,
E, F, G, H,
I, J, K, L,
M, N, O, P)
VALUES (
E, F, G, H,
I, J, K, L,
A, B, C, D,
M, N, O, P
)
```

Which meant it compiled without any issues but running it caused values to go into the wrong columns and eventually an error when a max length was breached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4.0.0.12 was the second early adopter release - a beta, in other words - and [was released in September 2013](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/09/oracle-sql-developer-v4ea2-is-now-available/). There was a third EA release, and there have been three production releases so far since [December](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/12/oracle-sql-developer-v4-is-live-top-10-reasons-to-upgrade-today/).

The [current version at the time of writing is 4.0.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) (4.0.2.15). Unless you have a pressing reason to stick to the early adopter/beta version you should probably just upgrade to the production version.

I can't immediately see anything relevant [on the SQL Developer forum](https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/development_tools/application_development_in_pl_sql/sql_developer_%28not_for_general_sql_plsql_questions%29), which is where early adopter issues were supposed to be reported. That doesn't mean it wasn't reported, or spotted internally, and fixed. I doubt they'd be very interested in this now if it has already been fixed in a later version, though.

If you upgrade and do still see this or any other bugs then [the release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-releasenotes-v4-1925251.html) say to report them on My Oracle Support.

Comment: Cheers. I have a newer version of SQL Developer that i'll try out. It might be a formatting issue, but it doesn't seem to happen with other people using SQL Developer so might just be a dodgy install/config.